# How can I efficiently generate a random X and Y value INSIDE of a polygon in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, point-in-polygon

So I'm creating a virtual mapping software that essentially breaks coordinates into Areas. An Area is comprised of a defined list of boundary coordinates (coordinates that make the outer rim of the area, which connect to one another).

With this software, I need to randomly select points in EACH area that reside INSIDE of the areas boundary coordinates. Each area is different from the other and can have many more or even less sides, but with a minimum of 3 sides and no maximum sides.

I currently have a solution in which I simply generate random numbers until the numbers are within the area. However, due to the quantity of Areas (have vastly different Boundary coordinates ranging in small to HUGE values) & the quantity of points (could be 1-100+) this tactic proves to be highly inefficient (takes a long time to finish running). I would like to hear peoples ideas or even experiences/work on how to optimize this so it isn't so sluggish.

I've created a small demo application to explain the situation better...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>

const int GenerateRandomNumberBetween(
   const int start,
   const int end)
{
   const int stable_end = ((end < start) ? start : end);
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 generator(rd());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(start, stable_end);

   return distribution(generator); // generates number in the range the distribution value 
}

class Area
{
public:
   Area()
   {
      // Define a primitive area for this example, but please note that this is a very basic area, and most areas are acctually much larger and have many more sides...
      // This sample area creates a triangle.

      //(-2, 2);
      boundaries_x_coordinates.push_back(-2);
      boundaries_y_coordinates.push_back(2);

      //(2, 2);
      boundaries_x_coordinates.push_back(2);
      boundaries_y_coordinates.push_back(2);

      //(-2, 2);
      boundaries_x_coordinates.push_back(-2);
      boundaries_y_coordinates.push_back(-2);
   }

   const bool InArea(
      const int x,
      const int y)
   {
      // This function works just fine, and can be ignored... I just included it to show that we check if the new coordinates are indeed within the given Area.
      int minX = 0;
      int maxX = 0;
      int minY = 0;
      int maxY = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < boundaries_x_coordinates.size(); i++)
      {
         if (boundaries_x_coordinates[0] < minX)
         {
            minX = boundaries_x_coordinates[0];
         }

         if (boundaries_x_coordinates[0] > maxX)
         {
            maxX = boundaries_x_coordinates[0];
         }

         if (boundaries_y_coordinates[1] < minY)
         {
            minY = boundaries_y_coordinates[1];
         }

         if (boundaries_y_coordinates[1] > maxY)
         {
            maxY = boundaries_y_coordinates[1];
         }
      }

      if (boundaries_x_coordinates.size() < 3)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (x < minX || x > maxX || y < minY || y > maxY)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         size_t i, j, c = 0;
         for (i = 0, j = boundaries_x_coordinates.size() - 1; i < boundaries_x_coordinates.size(); j = i++)
         {
            if (((boundaries_y_coordinates[i] > y) != (boundaries_y_coordinates[j] > y)) &&
               (x < (boundaries_x_coordinates[j] - boundaries_x_coordinates[i]) * (y - boundaries_y_coordinates[i]) /
               (boundaries_y_coordinates[j] - boundaries_y_coordinates[i]) + boundaries_x_coordinates[i]))
            {
               c = !c;
            }
         }
         return (c == 0) ? false : true;
      }
   }

   std::vector<int> GenerateRandomPointInsideArea()
   {
      int minX = 0, maxX = 0, minY = 0, maxY = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < boundaries_x_coordinates.size(); i++)
      {
         if (boundaries_x_coordinates[i] < minX)
         {
            minX = boundaries_x_coordinates[i];
         }

         if (boundaries_x_coordinates[i] > maxX)
         {
            maxX = boundaries_x_coordinates[i];
         }

         if (boundaries_y_coordinates[i] < minY)
         {
            minY = boundaries_y_coordinates[i];
         }

         if (boundaries_y_coordinates[i] > maxY)
         {
            maxY = boundaries_y_coordinates[i];
         }
      }

      // The problem is here, this do while statement takes a tremendous of time to execute in realistic Areas simply because it takes a 
      // long time to generate all the random coordinates inside the area (sometimes could be as little as 1 coordinate set, sometimes could be 100).
      int random_x = 0;
      int random_y = 0;
      do
      {
         random_x = GenerateRandomNumberBetween(minX, maxX);
         random_y = GenerateRandomNumberBetween(minY, maxY);
      } while (!InArea(random_x, random_y));

      std::vector<int> random_coordinates;
      random_coordinates.push_back(random_x);
      random_coordinates.push_back(random_y);

      return random_coordinates;
   }

private:
   std::vector<int> boundaries_x_coordinates;
   std::vector<int> boundaries_y_coordinates;
};

int main()
{
   Area* sample_area = new Area();

   std::vector<int> random_coordinates = sample_area->GenerateRandomPointInsideArea();

   printf("Random Coordinate: (%i, %i)\n", random_coordinates[0], random_coordinates[1]);

   // Pause to see results.
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

The sample output would output a coordinate set inside the Area... In this specific example my first run it output:

```
Random Coordinate: (-1, 1)
```

I've read that dividing the Area into triangles,then picking a random triangle, and generating a random coordinate within that triangle is the best solution... But I've no idea how to generate triangles out of an Areas coordinate set, and if I could do that... Why wouldn't I just use that technique to choose a random coordinate...?

--------Edit--------

Thanks to Matt Timmermans I was able to solve this issue by further researching the subject and applying most of what Matt explained below.

If anyone else is having difficulty with the subject, here's what I came up with (mostly what Matt mentioned, with some changes)

1) Triangulate the polygon into multiple triangles, in my case I needed a simple and lightweight C++ solution with 0 graphical interfaces. I managed to find a working class online called Triangulate here http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml.

2) Randomly choose a triangle using weighted probability. If a triangle occupies 80% of the original polygon, it should be chosen roughly 80% of the time.

At this point in the process I was able to do some research and find some variations, the simplest of which is the one I chose (as seen below).

3) Once you have chosen a triangle, generate a uniformly random point within this triangle. This can be accomplished through the use of this formula:

```
P = (1 - sqrt(r1)) * A + (sqrt(r1) * (1 - r2)) * B + (sqrt(r1) * r2) * C
```

Where r1 and r2 are random numbers between 0 and 1 as described in this article section 4.2...
[http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~funk/tog02.pdf](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml)

You are done, that's all it takes!

Alternatively, you can continue with what Matt suggested, both methods seem to work perfectly in any case.. Which is...

3) Copy the triangle and create a parallelogram with it and the original triangle. Using the following formulas:

```
M=(A+C)/2
P4=M-(B-M)

Where...
M is a midpoint in the original triangle where the copied triangle will connect.
A,B,C are the 3 vertices in the original triangle
P4 is the new point the forms the parallelogram with the other 3 points of the original triangle.
```

4) Generate a random number from within the parallelogram by generating a random x and y value between the min and max x and y values of the parallelogram until you are within the parallelogram.
5) If the random coordinate is INSIDE the COPIED triangle, map it to the corresponding point in the original triangle, if not you're done.

Comment: If you want to improve/optimize working code you're better off asking at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, I've never even heard of that website... But I will try.

Comment: Could you maybe floodfill the polygon with say, blue, and then randomly pick a pixel till you get a blue one? Just do it in the minimum containing box to save time.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't exactly fill it with a color as it's just virtual (no graphical interface to it). However, I'm already kind of doing that by specifying the Min and Max X and Y values when picking a random number for each coordinate.

Comment: You don't have to draw it on a real, physical screen - you can draw on a virtual canvas, or virtual device context etc.

Comment: I think you should initialise `minX` and `minY` to MAXINT, rather than zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Divide the polygon into triangles
2. Randomly choose a triangle, giving each triangle a probability proportional to its area
3. Copy the triangle to make a parallelogram
4. Pick a random point in the parallelogram by randomly choosing coordinates in the base and height directions
5. If the random point is in the copy of the triangle, not in the original triangle, then map it to the corresponding point in the original triangle.
6. Done -- you're left with a random point in the chosen triangle, which is a random point chosen uniformly from the polygon.

Comment: I've read about this method, although I'm not sure how I can pragmatically divide each area into triangles... Doing it manually is a no go. As far as I understand it... If I can generate random triangles inside the area, then that would be the same as generating a random point so need for the triangles... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not random triangles -- you divide the area into triangles that cover it perfectly.  If it's a convex polygon, then you can pick one of the points and use the triangles that each edge makes with that point.

Comment: I thought about what you said, so if I understand correctly. You're saying to connect a start point to the 2nd point over to create a triangle between point 1, point 2, and point 3(2nd point over) for EACH point. Which sounds like it has potential (And probably does I'm just still a bit confused)... But what about the triangles that are formed outside of the area? Such as in this quick paint image I drew up... https://puu.sh/rIaFb/5eb5ad7e2e.png also wouldn't copying the triangle to form a parallelogram cause the coordinate chosen to go outside of the area if the random spot is in the copy?

Comment: Yes, you have it right.  Picking one point only works for convex polygons, and the polygon in the .png is not convex.  There are a bunch of ways to triangulate non-convex polygons.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

Comment: Also, yes. see point (5) above -- if the random point is the the copy, map it to the corresponding point in the original triangle.  Every point in the original triangle has 2 points in the parallelogram, so it's still uniform

Comment: @MattTimmermans - what about generating uniform random points in a circle or square that encloses the polygon, and throwing away the ones outside the polygon? Depending on the shape of the polygon, I'm wondering about the overhead of throwing away points versus dividing the polygon into numerous triangles.

Comment: That depends on the shape -- a long, thin shape has a bounding circle with a much larger area than the shape.  Triangulating is fast when you get down to it.

Comment: Hmmm thanks @MattTimmermans. I think this will be the way for me to go... Now I just need to do research on how exactly to incorporate triangulation and which algorithm is best to use (preferably the easiest to understand/implement haha).

Comment: I just finished my implementation of this, thank you @MattTimmermans. I've updated my question with what to me seems like a more efficient method for generating the random point while still using the majority of your answer. What do you think?